# Laravel 5 inject values in boot self::creating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to inject a few values into columns that will always be set to save time when creating a new record in the database.

I have tried:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function($item){
            $item->created_by = Auth::user()->id(); // Logged in user's id
        });
...
```

But this gives me the error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1987:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id()
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either `Auth::id()` or `Auth::user()->id`. As the error message say, there is no method called `id` on the query builder.

You should also change `self::creating` to `static::creating` to work better if the class is extended.